DreamHost (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
I'm on dreamhost and I keep having these errors in my error log. The site shows my custom 500 Error content, and the backend setting and customization pages, but all of the front facing content is showing 500 errors. DH does not give access to apache/etc configuration as far as I know.
Here are the errors, shortened:
\[fcgid:warn\] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
\[core:error\]  End of script output before headers: index.php

I already updated to a VPS for more memory, added this to my dreamhost phprc file and verified the changes with websitename.com/phpinfo.php:
memory_limit = 300M
upload_max_filesize = 600M
post_max_size = 650M
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 0
; {{{ The following lines were automatically added by DreamHost
zend_extension=opcache.so
; }}} That's all from DreamHost

